# How to solve " 'PathCollection' object has no attribute 'yaxis' " error?

Tags: python, matplotlib, visual-studio-code

I'm a MSc Student and I used to make graphs and plots with commercial packages like OriginPro, Excel and Matlab. Although these softwares provide a great user experience, there are some major disadvantages as they are specific OS dependent and, in general, very expensive.

Hence, I started to learn Python using matplotlib library with VS Code, however I'm having some problems with some library functions and statements that seems to be standard from matplotlib and numPy, but it doesnt work.

For example, I'm making some templates for scatter plots and I can't control minor ticks because it doesn't recognize the statements `xaxix` and `yaxix`:

Sample of the code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator, AutoMinorLocator

.
.
.

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(x_pixels/my_dpi, y_pixels/my_dpi), dpi=my_dpi)
ax = plt.scatter(x*format_x, y*format_y, s = size, alpha = transparency, color = color, label = legend_text)

.
.
.

# Major Ticks
plt.tick_params(axis = 'both', which = 'major', length = majorT_length, direction = majorT_direction, color = majorT_color, labelsize = label_size, top = 'on', right = 'on')

# Minor Ticks
plt.minorticks_on()
plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='minor', length = minorT_length, direction = minorT_direction, color = minorT_color, top = 'on', right = 'on')
ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(AutoMinorLocator(2))
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(AutoMinorLocator(2))

# Figure Layout
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig(output_file, dpi=my_dpi, bbox_inches=borders)

plt.show()
```

and the Terminal show this error:

[image]

```
  File "c:/Users/luagu/Desktop/Python Matplotlib Training/Scatter_Template.py", line 128, in <module>
    ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(AutoMinorLocator(2))
AttributeError: 'PathCollection' object has no attribute 'yaxis'
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please include the error message directly, not as an image.

Answer (score 5):

You wrote `ax = plt.scatter` but your `ax` here is an artist returned by the `scatter` method, not an `Axes` object. What you want to do is:

```
plt.scatter(...)
...
ax = plt.gca()
ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(AutoMinorLocator(2))
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(AutoMinorLocator(2))
```

Comment: Oh, it's working now! 
Actually it makes sense because first you need to get axis through plt.gca() and then use the command. Thank you! :)